# Emit not firing event more than once

Tags: contract-development, events, contract-debugging

I'm experimenting a little bit with the blockchain, I'm currently trying to send from an oracle an address to store on the blockchain through a smart contract. The code (very simple and without checks) is the following:

```
function addNewContract(address _newAddress) public {
    emit LoggingStrings("New address added!");
    //require(msg.sender == oracleAddress); --> commented because I don't need this at the moment, just playing
    contractAddressArray.push(_newAddress);
    contractNumber++;
    emit NewAddressAdded(_newAddress);
}
```

I correctly log the _newAddress received in the Node.js console of my DAPP, but this happens only once. I have a routine that every 10 seconds repeats the same code to store a contract on the blockchain:

```
export const addNewContract = (contractAddress) => {
 return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  account().then(account => {
    console.log("Adding new contract: " + contractAddress);
    contract.addNewContract(contractAddress, {from: account}, (err, res) => {
      console.log("New contract added from frontend: " + contractAddress + "  " + err);
      if(err === null){
        resolve(res);
      } else {
        reject(err);
      }
    });
  });
 }); 
};
```

I see the console.log prints, but I don't see the events emitted anymore. Is that because that's how it is supposed to work, or am I doing something wrong?

Thanks!

EDIT: Here is the code of the logging

```
export const update = (callback) => {
  contract.LoggingString((error, result) => callback(error, result));
}

const consume = () => {
  console.log("consumer started");
  update((error, result) => {
    console.log("NEW EVENT");
    console.log("DATA: ");
    console.log(result.args);
    console.log("\n");
  });
};
```

Comment: Where's the code for how you see the first emittance of the `LoggingStrings(...)` event log?

Comment: Edited the question and added!

Answer (score 1):

Your `update` function appears to only `consume` your event once:

```
export const update = (callback) => {
  contract.LoggingString((error, result) => callback(error, result));
}
```

Once the `callback` you pass into this function has run, execution is complete and so further events have no `callback`s to fire.

Instead, you want to use web3 to subscribe to a stream of events from your contract via:

```
myInstantiatedContract.contract.events.LoggingStrings([options][, callback])
```

...which will fire your `callback` for every event that is seen.

You can find more info in **[the docs here.](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-contract.html?highlight=events#events)**

Comment: I tried to follow the link on the docs without success (can't find the docs related to events). `myContract.events.LoggingStrings([options][, callback])` this doesn't work as "events" appears to be undefined thus I cannot call `LoggingStrings`

Comment: I've edited the link I posted to go to the section in docs on events in web3, where that piece of code I posted was taken from (and edited to fit your code).

If `events` are undefined, you may be using a different version of web3 where `events` may be found via: `myInstantiatedContract.contract.events`.